# Global Error Handling in Task.Run

Tags: c#, wpf, error-handling

I have a wpf c# app.

I normally use a global error handler to catch all errors:

```
private void Application_DispatcherUnhandledException(object sender, System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(() => Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.MessageBox.Show(e.Exception.ToString(), "Error",
          MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error)));
        e.Handled = true;
        InformedWorkerDataService.Common.Shared.RecordMessage(e.Exception.ToString(), true);
    }
    finally { }
}
```

However, if start off a task.run 'bit of code' and it throws an error then i have observed that error is not caught:

```
Task.Run(() =>
{
    throw and error here    
});
```

so I have to put a 'Try-Catch' thing in to capture it:

```
Task.Run(() =>
{
    try
    {
        throw an error here
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        do  something with error
    }
});
```

~ which defeats the object of having a Global Error handler

What should I do?

Comment: try [`TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.unobservedtaskexception(v=vs.110).aspx) event

Comment: @dkozl cool - thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an [`TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.unobservedtaskexception(v=vs.110).aspx) event that you can use

```
TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += (s, e) => {
    e.Exception  //The Exception that went unobserved.
    e.SetObserved(); //Marks the Exception as "observed," thus preventing it from triggering exception escalation policy which, by default, terminates the process.
};
```

> Occurs when a faulted task's unobserved exception is about to trigger exception escalation policy, which, by default, would terminate the process.
>
> This application domain-wide event provides a mechanism to prevent exception escalation policy (which, by default, terminates the process) from triggering

Comment: I am glad you posted an answer so that i can accept it. Do I still have to set this: <ThrowUnobservedTaskExceptions enabled="true"/> ?

Comment: If you handle your exception then not. Normally I don't set `ThrowUnobservedTaskExceptions`. If there is an exception then I'd rather handle/log it then hide it

Comment: I highly recommend not relying on the UnobservedTaskException if you desire showing a UI notification when an exception occurs. In my experience this handler does not run in real time and will show the message box long after the exception occurs. The stack trace etc. is obviously still correct, but the user experience is very confusing. I definitely still recommend using an in-line catch for anything but truly, truly unexpected exceptions.

Comment: @AndrewHanlon just read your comment. I have experienced that behavior. You are right keep the it in-line when using in this context- thanks

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in my comment to the accepted answer, the `TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException` is not guarenteed to fire in real time with the exception being thrown. This means that using this handler for user notification can be quite confusing as the user action and error notification will not happen synchronously. For user driven handling of 'unexpected' task exceptions, you could create helper methods as below and use `TaskEx.Run` instead of `Task.Run`:

```
public static class TaskEx
{
    public static Task Run(Action function)
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                function();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                TraceEx.TraceException(ex);
                //Dispatch your MessageBox etc.
            }
        });
    }
}
```